# search for multiple values in comma separated column (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I need to fetch all records where these (`5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5`) values exists in `categories_id` column.
The value that I need to search in `categories_id` can be multiple because it coming from the form.

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id                                   | name        | alias       | description | categories_id                                                                                                                                                 |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 5565c08d-9f18-4b76-9cae-4a8261af48f5 | Honeycolony | honeycolony | null        | ["5565bffd-7f64-494c-8950-4bef61af48f5"]                                                                                                                      |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| c8f16660-32cf-11e6-b73c-1924f891ba4d | LOFT        | loft        | null        | ["5565bffd-25bc-4b09-8a83-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5"]                                        |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 5565c17f-80d8-4390-aadf-4a8061af48f5 | Fawn Shoppe | fawn-shoppe | null        | ["5565bffd-25bc-4b09-8a83-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-0744-4740-81f5-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5"] |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have this function which work as `in_array` function php.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.arraycontain(
    x json,
    y json)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
  DECLARE a text;b text;
  BEGIN
    FOR a IN SELECT json_array_elements_text($1)
    LOOP
      FOR b IN SELECT json_array_elements_text($2)
      LOOP
        IF a = b THEN
          RETURN TRUE;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN FALSE ;
  END;
  $BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.arraycontain(json, json)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

But when I do this:

```
select * from "stores" 
where arrayContain(stores.categories_id::JSON,'["5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5"]')
```

it shows

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
>   DETAIL:  The input string
>   ended unexpectedly.
>   CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1:   SQL state: 22P02

here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/54a26/6) (I couldn't update the arraycontain function in fiddle.)

My expected output from the fiddle is it should return last 3 rows that is `Furbish Studio,Fawn Shoppe AND LOFT` if search using this values `["5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5"])`

I am open for any recommendation.
I also tried this query below but it returns empty.

```
select id
from stores
where string_to_array(categories_id,',') && array['5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5','5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5'];
```

**EDIT:**

This code is actually a filter to filter data. So if I only filter using categories it didn't work but if there is a query before it it works

```
select * from "stores" 
    where name like '%ab%' and  arrayContain(stores.categories_id::JSON,'["5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5"]')
```

also the thing that amaze me is that the `'%ab%'` must contain more than two character if there's below <2 it will throw error. what could be wrong.

Comment: Why isn't `categories_id` defined as `jsonb` or `text[]`? That would make things a lot easier.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `categories_id` is defined as `text`. converting categories_id from text to jsonb can cause any errors?

Comment: Yes, that's my question. Why not use a better data type?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please check my updated comment.

Answer (score 1):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2bdf8467d95f6e372fd8f4be2aff6469)

You can use the `?|` operator, which takes a `jsonb` array (your column in that case) and checks a `text` array if any elements are included:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE categories_id ?| '{5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5,5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5}'
```

---

If your `categories_id` is not of type `json` (which is what the error message says) but a simple `text` array, you can compare two `text` arrays directly using the `&&` operator:

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c50139c9a766ffe4dee1f404339d5a2f)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE categories_id && '{5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5,5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5}'
```

Comment: Both of your code works in fiddle. The second one is having { braces where else i have [ square brackets. So when i tried. it doesn't work because i saved it as array. The question is do i need to convert [] to {} or i convert datatype for categories_id from text to jsonb?

Comment: Try to reproduce it in a fiddle as well

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine so perhaps sqlfiddle is the problem.
Try changing the separator in the schema building part to / (instead of ;) and make sure you have the correct version for Postgresql.  json_array_elements_text is not supported in 9.3 (you can use json_array_elements instead in this case).

Also skip the " in the select statement.

Look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/918b75/1

There might be an error in your data.  Perhaps categories_id is an empty string somewhere.

Try this to see the offending data if any.

```
do $$ 
declare 
    r record;
    b boolean;
begin
for r in (select * from stores) loop
b:= arrayContain(r.categories_id::JSON,'["5565bffd-b1c8-4556-ae5d-4bef61af48f5","5565bffd-cd78-4e6f-ae13-4bef61af48f5"]') ;
end loop;
exception
    when others 
        then raise notice '%,%',r,r.categories_id;
        return;
end;
$$
```

Best regards.
Bjarni

Comment: I tried this for the record of 30300 and still the same error `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.` but if i limit it to 10 it works anything greater than 13 doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "record of 30300"?

Comment: I have this much(number) of rows in my table.

Comment: I suspect an error in your data.  I edited my answer for a code to look for it.

Comment: Yes i have received this error [just paste it here](https://justpaste.it/267yi)

Comment: This page returns "not found"

Comment: This is difficult to read.  Please replace then "raise notice '%',r;" with "then raise notice '%',r.categories_id;" and show output.

Comment: This is the output `NOTICE:  ["5565bffd-7f64-494c-8950-4bef61af48f5"]
DO`

Comment: My mistake.  There was an error in the "debug" code.  Please look again in the answer - you should now see the invalid json.

Comment: here is the link for the code [here](https://justpaste.it/24lrv)

Comment: Could it be that "[object Object]" is in the categories_id column?

Comment: code to get exception did help me but another code helped me check  my edit